# Use MultipartEntityBuilder to send data from Android through REST

Tags: android, web-services, rest, post, multipart

I'm trying to send from my android app to a REST WebService some simple strings. However, in my WebService I'm always receiving a null value. [EDIT]I'm using Multipart because I'll also want to send images along with strings in the future.

Here is my android code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entityBuilder.addTextBody("email", "teste");
entityBuilder.addTextBody("password", "123");
httppost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

if(statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "=]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    //This line is executed
} else {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "=[", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Here is my web service code:

```
@POST
@Path("/cadastrarUsuario")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UsuarioVO postUsuario(@PathParam("email") final String email) {
    System.out.println("E-mail: " + email); 

    return usuario;

}
```

I'm always receiving email as null. I guess @PathParam or @FormParam won't really work here. But what is the right way to receive the params?

Answer (score 0):

Multipart is more suitable for file uploads. In your case, a lightweight form submission would be appropriate. The body then contains e.g. `email=teste&pwd=123`, the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You should know that [it's not recommended](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) to use `HttpClient` in Android >= GINGERBREAD. The preferred choice is `HttpURLConnection`.

Since HttpURLConnection's interface is not easy to use, there are some wrapper libraries which make life easier. [Here is a list](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background). In case you chose the library I provided (with the very liberal MIT-Licence), you could create your REST request like this:

```java
Webb webb = Webb.create();
webb.setBaseUri("http://myserver/app-path");
Response<String> response = webb
            .post("/cadastrarUsuario")
            .param("email", "teste")
            .param("pwd", "123")
            .asString();

if (response.isSuccess()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "response: " + response.getBody());
} else {
    Log.w(TAG, "HTTP-Code: " + response.getStatusCode());
}
```

There are other types you can receive, e.g. `JSONObject` or `byte[]`. In this example we expect a simple String.

Your Java REST resource should read a bit different:

```
@POST
@Path("/cadastrarUsuario")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) // <-- 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UsuarioVO postUsuario(@FormParam("email") final String email,
                             @FormParam("pwd") final String pwd) {
    System.out.println("E-mail: " + email); 

    return usuario;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick response. I forgot to say that I'm using Multipart because I'll also want to send images along with strings in the future. Can any of these wraper libraries you mentioned send image and string at the same post request?

Comment: What kind of Strings (how many?, how long?) do you want to send along with the image? And do you have the image in memory or as a file on sdcard?

Comment: I want to send the email, the password and an image as a byte array that is stored in the memory. I already have some ideia on how to get the image and compress it.

Comment: email and password sounds like some kind of authentication header to me. If you are compliant to standards, e.g. Basic Authentication, you could leverage some existent software components. Maybe your server-side REST library already has a way to intercept requests and authorize the calls.

Comment: I ended up converting blob to string using base64 and it's working well so far. Thank you anyways :)